# In complexity, Is the relationship between P and R known?

Tags: computational-complexity, computability

The relationship between P and NP is unknown; However, we can ask an "easier" question, what is the relationship between P and R (=decidable languages)? In other words, is there a (decidable) problem shown to be not solvable in polynomial time? [This wikipedia diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexity_class#Relationships_between_complexity_classes) states that EXPSPACE is strictly contained in R, meaning that P is strictly contained in R, however, I couldn't find any further details on this. Thanks!

Comment: Given any total computable function $\phi$, you can define a language that takes more than $\phi$ time to compute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any total recursive function $\rho:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$, you can define a decidable subset of $\mathbb N$ which is not decidable by any Turing machine in less than $\rho$ time.

Essentially, this is done by a diagonal argument, by finding a recursive language $L:\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$ which does not agree with any function that takes $\rho(n)$ time for all $n$.

If $\phi_e$ is an effective enumeration of computable Turing functions, we say $\phi_{e,s}(n)\downarrow$ if the Turing machine finished computation in time $s$ given input $n$.  For any $N$, we enumerate $1\leq e \leq N$ such that for all $1\leq n \leq N$, $\phi_{e,\rho(n)}(n)\downarrow$ and all resulting values are in $\{0,1\}$, and we pick the smallest such $e$ which we have not previously excluded.  Then we define $L(N)=1-\phi_e(N)$.  (If there is no such $e$, then we defint $L(N)=0$.) Now we added this $e$, if it existed, to the "previously excluded" set for later steps.  Note that this all takes a finite amount of time for each $N$.

This induction has the effect that if $\phi_e(n)$ runs in time $\rho(n)$ for all $n$ and always returns $0,1$,  then it gets excluded at some step. (This requires proof, but basically you can show that $\phi_e$ will get excluded by step $N=2e$.)

The resulting $L$ will be a total function which takes only the values $0,1$ and which is not equal to any computable function which takes $\rho(n)$ time to compute for all $n$.

Now, if $\rho(n)=2^n$, then this means that the resulting $L$ cannot, in particular, be computed in polynomial time.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the third paragraph? It is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Not sure it can be made much clearer - it is couched in terms of computability theory that you might not be familiar with. Essentially, we are doing what we normally do in a diagonal argument - making sure that any suitable $\phi_e$ disagrees with $L$ at some point.  The limit $\rho$ lets us enumerate the functions which halt in the specified time for $1\leq n \leq N$, so we can define $L$ so that it disagrees with each function that halts in that amount of time.  But I agree, it is tricky and technical.

Comment: Maybe I'll try to be more specific: What do you mean by "and all resulting values are in {0,1}", and what do you mean by "and we pick the smallest such e which we have not previously excluded"? Also, what is a computable Turing function? is it what I know by "computable function"?

Comment: I just mean $\phi_e$ is the computable function computed by the $e$th Turing machine, for some enumeration of the Turing machines.

Comment: If $\phi_e$ is the decision function for some language, then $\phi_e(n)$ is always either $0$ or $1$, so we don't need to worry about the $\phi_e$ which take other values. So I just means, "consider the set of $e$ which run in the correct time and for which $\phi_e(n)$ always takes the value $0$ or $1$ for $1\leq n \leq N$.

Comment: "Excluded" is defined in the induction - once we have picked the $e$ and set $L(N)$ to disagree with $\phi_e(N)$, we consider $e$ "previously excluded" for later steps in the recursion. Without this, we'd just be excluding the same $e$ over and over again.

Comment: It is clearer now, thanks!

Comment: How can we show that $\phi _e$ will be excluded by step 2e?

Comment: In step $N\geq e$, $e$ is always an option for our exclusion, so, unless $e$ is excluded, each stup must either exclude some other element less than $e$. Since a number can only be excluded once, we must get to excluding $e$ by $N=2e$.

Comment: But this isn't necessary for the proof - we can just say that since each N gives us strictly bigger e, each $\phi _e$ will be excluded by some step N large enough. Right?

Comment: Yes, you just have to show that there is some step $N$ large enough to force $\phi_e$ to be excluded. It's just easier in this case to prove that $N=2e$ is large enough explicitly. (If you aren't careful about exclusions, you don't get this result, for example.)

Comment: Note that if you wanted to define $L$ so that $L(n)$ cannot be computed in $C\rho(n)$ for any constant $C$, then you could still make this same sort of argument, only with $\phi_{s,N\rho(n)}(n)\downarrow$ as the condition, and, if $\phi_e$ was a $\{0,1\}$ function which computed in $C\rho(n)$ time for all $n$, then $e$ would be excluded by step $N>e+max(C,e)$. But $C$ is almost certainly not computable in terms of $e$, so this means that, although we know such $e$ will eventually be excluded, we don't "know" by when.

Answer (score 0):

By the [Time Hierarchy Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem), we know that class P is strictly contained in class EXPTIME. A natural example of problems that lie in EXPTIME but not P (aka the EXPTIME-complete problems) is the decision problem of whether a deterministic Turing machine would halt on a certain input within $k$ steps.

Now EXPTIME, by definition, is a class of decision problems and is therefore contained in R (and, by Time Hierarchy Theorem, is strictly contained in R). So it follows that $P \subsetneq R$.